# UIScrollView Detect scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

In my program I have UIScrollView. And I adding buttons dynamically on that. In scrollView there is a property

`[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];`

And when I scrolling on next page buttons which must be at the top moving up for a few pixels.
So I think I need programmatically set scrollView scroll position. How can I detect end of scrolling and set scroll position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this scroll view delegate method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` to detect the end of scrolling.

If you need to set the position then call `[myScrollView setFrame: myCGRect];` to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for response =) It is possible to know current page of scroll?

Comment: I've not tested this, but it should help... if you call myScrollView.contentOffset.y (or x if you need this axis) and then divide it by the height of your scroll view and then round this number up or down, it should be the page number.